# want to add multile do_until checks while worksheet change

Tags: excel, vba

the below code is working fine for me, now i want to do same calculation for E22 & I22, if i add seperate Do until the code dosent exit at count of 19, it loops further, can anyone helpme

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 Dim i As Long
    
Range("E21").Value = 1
i = 1

' Loop until I21 is less than 1.02 or E21 reaches 19
Do Until Range("I21").Value < 1.02 Or Range("E21").Value = 19
    Range("E21").Value = i
    
    ' Check if value of I21 is less than 1.02 after updating E21
    If Range("I21").Value < 1.02 Then
        Exit Do
    End If
    
    ' Increment i
    i = i + 1
    
    ' Stop at 19 if unable to reach target value of I21
    If i > 19 Then
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop

End sub
```

Comment: Be more clear what you want to happen. Do you want BOTH E21 and I21 to meet the requirement? Either one then the other, check both?

Comment: above code is checking for one row, next i want to check next row with values of E22 & I22 instead of E21 & I21